# Bash - Compare 2 lists of files with their md5 check sums

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, md5

I have 2 lists with files with their md5sum checks. The lists have different paths even that the files are the same. I want to check the md5 sums of each file. We are talking for thousands of files and that's why I need script to show me only the differences. The first list is the vanilla and the second is the current state  of the files. I want to find which of the files are changed/different than the original. To do that I want to compare the 2 lists. On every line there is md5 sum and file location/name. Did anyone have an idea how to do that? And what happens if there is one extra file in one of the lists?!

Example of content in first file with check sums (vanila list):

```
df7a0edcb7994581430379db56d8d53b  /home/user/vanila/file-1.php
e1af39e94239a944440ab2925393ae60  /home/user/vanila/file-2.php
ce74e43d24d9c36cd579e932ee94b152  /home/user/vanila/file-3.php
95b7d47ed7134912270f8d3059100e8c  /home/user/vanila/file-4.php
```

Example of content in second file with check sums (active list):

```
df7a0edcb7994581430379db56d8d53b  /home/user/file-1.php
94b2a24a1fc9883246fc103f22818930  /home/user/file-1.1.php
e1af39e94239a944440ab2925393ae60  /home/user/file-2.php
ce74e43d24d9c36cd579e932ee94b152  /home/user/file-3.php
f5233ee990c50aade7c4e3ab9b4fe524  /home/user/file-4.php
```

Expecting results:

```
To show me that file-4.php is with different md5 sum.
If shows that there is an extra file (file-1.1.php) it's a bonus!
```

Comment: Provide the input file and your required output of the same

Comment: @Inian the example of the files' content was added and the expected results were added also!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attempt using `Awk` which is the right tool meant for this,

```
awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filearray[$1]=$NF; next }!($1 in filearray){printf "%s has a different md5sum\n",$NF}' file2 file1
file4.php has a different md5sum
```

Where, `file2` and `file1` are as follows

```
$ cat file1
df7a0edcb7994581430379db56d8d53b  /home/user/vanila/file-1.php
e1af39e94239a944440ab2925393ae60  /home/user/vanila/file-2.php
ce74e43d24d9c36cd579e932ee94b152  /home/user/vanila/file-3.php
95b7d47ed7134912270f8d3059100e8c  /home/user/vanila/file-4.php

$ cat file2
df7a0edcb7994581430379db56d8d53b  /home/user/file-1.php
94b2a24a1fc9883246fc103f22818930  /home/user/file-1.1.php
e1af39e94239a944440ab2925393ae60  /home/user/file-2.php
ce74e43d24d9c36cd579e932ee94b152  /home/user/file-3.php
f5233ee990c50aade7c4e3ab9b4fe524  /home/user/file-4.php
```

To find the file is not present in one and not in other,

```
awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filelist[$NF]=$NF; next;}!($NF in filelist){printf "%s is an extra file",$NF}' file1 file2
file-1.1.php is an extra file
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! However I'm thinking of another approach to show me of there are any extra files. I will post it once I have it! Thank you again for the fast response!

Comment: @SasnycoN: Happy to help!

Comment: The update is also working. My other approach was to take the "Active list" (file2) and update its paths with the one from the "Vanilla list" (file1) by using `sed`. After that to run the following

    `md5sum -c --quiet file2`

This will be run over the vanilla files and will show me if there are files with different md5 sums and if there are files that can't be found in the vanilla.

Comment: @SasnycoN: Good if you can find a solution of your own!

Comment: my main concern is which one will be more faster and less resource heavy but this will know after some testing. ;) Again thank you for your answer!

Comment: One more question. How to add the file path to the results if I use your solutions?