# Bash - editing code line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, md5

This question is related to [Bash - Compare 2 lists of files with their md5 check sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614641/bash-compare-2-lists-of-files-with-their-md5-check-sums/)

My question is how to edit the following codes to show the entire path of the file instead just the name of it:

```
awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filearray[$1]=$NF; next }!($1 in filearray){printf "%s has a different md5sum\n",$NF}' file1 file2
```

and

```
awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filelist[$NF]=$NF; next;}!($NF in filelist){printf "%s is an extra file",$NF}' file1 file2
```

For more information please review the other question!

Thank you all for the time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `GNU Awk` string manipulation [split-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), to split the matching line, in this case a `$0` and store it in the `array` as individual elements.

```
 awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filearray[$1]=$NF; next }!($1 in filearray){split($0,array," ");printf "%s has a different md5sum or do not exist in the vanilla core files\n",array[2]}' file2 file1
/home/user/vanila/file-4.php has a different md5sum or do not exist in the vanilla core files
```

and for the file(s)

```
 awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filelist[$NF]=$NF; next;}!($NF in filelist){split($0,array," "); printf "%s is an extra file\n",array[2]}' file1 file2
/home/user/file-1.1.php is an extra file
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm beginner in bash scripting and especially in using `GNU Awk` and that's why the code is very complicated for me!

Comment: @SasnycoN: Posting an attempt of yourself, tends to attract more answers! cheers! learn more about `Awk` as it is so powerful.